# android change toolbar text color with scrollview

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm trying to animate CollapsingToolbarLayout title with scroll.My goal is to animate text center position ,right now text animate left side.Here is a my xml code

My goal is to receive like this result.I would to change CollapsingToolbarLayout text with toolbar text in center size and also I would to change toolbar background color with scroll position .

How I can solve this problem?
thanks

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="321dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewCollapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/winterscenery"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:background="#ff00"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/content_text_one" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/content_button" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/content_text_two" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: are you using the default textview in the toolbar? I mean do you do something like `toolbar.setTitle()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for any changes in to CollapsingToolbarLayout..
make style..

```
<style name="coll_toolbar_title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_13sdp</item>
</style>
```

then set.. using id..

```
collapseLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.coll_toolbar_title)
```

mange scrolling to change here you can change toolbar background ...

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    boolean isShow = true;
    int scrollRange = -1;

    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        if (scrollRange == -1) {

        }
        if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
            // expend
            collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Title");
            isShow = true;
        } else if(isShow) {
            // collepse
            collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(" ");//carefull there should a space between double quote otherwise it wont work 
            isShow = false;
        }
    }
});
```